# Clear a value from a textfield and fill that value in an other textfield?

Tags: javascript, pdf, if-statement

i have the following code:

```
var s1 = this.getField("One").value;
var s2 = this.getField("Two").value;
var s3 = this.getField("Three").value;
var s1n = this.getField("One");
var s2n = this.getField("Two");
var s3n = this.getField("Three");

if(s1.length > 0) & (s2.length == 0) & (s3.length == 0){
  s1n = '' & s2n = s1 & s3n = ''
  else if (s1.length > 0) & (s2.length > 0) & (s3.length == 0){
          s1n = s1 & s2n = '' & s3n = s3
          else if (s1.length > 0) & (s2.length > 0) & (s3.length > 0){
          s1n = s1 & s2n = s2 & s3n = s3
}}}
```

I have three textfields in a row. 
If i fill out "One" only i want clear the value in "One" and fill that value in "Two".
If i fill out "One" and "Two" i want to clear the value in "Two" and fill that value in "Three".
If i fill out "One" and "Two" and "Three" i want to do nothing.
But with the code above i get an syntax error. What i have to do, to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work

```js
function check() {
  var s1 = document.getElementById("ip1").value;
  var s2 = document.getElementById("ip2").value;
  var s3 = document.getElementById("ip3").value;

  var s1n = document.getElementById("ip1");
  var s2n = document.getElementById("ip2");
  var s3n = document.getElementById("ip3");

  if ((s1.length > 0) && (s2.length == 0) && (s3.length == 0)) {
    s2n.value = s1n.value;
    s1n.value = "";
  }

  if ((s1.length > 0) && (s2.length > 0) && (s3.length == 0)) {
    s3n.value = s2n.value;
    s2n.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ip1" placeholder="Enter value 1">
<input type="text" id="ip2" placeholder="Enter value 2">
<input type="text" id="ip3" placeholder="Enter value 3">
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="check()">
```